# AngularJS Filter from "left to right" in values

Tags: html, angularjs, filter

So I've looked far and wide for a solution for this and come up short and would highly appreciate some help.

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('theController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.array = [
{name:'Adam Smith'},
{name:'Smith Adam'}  
];
}]);
```

HTML:

```
 <html ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="theController">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchInput" />
<ul ng-show="searchInput" class="ng-hide">
<li ng-repeat="arr in array | filter:searchInput">{{ arr.name }}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The way this works now is that if I type "Adam" into the text input field, I will get the results:

-Adam Smith

-Smith Adam

My desired results for typing "Adam" (or just "A" for that matter) should be only:

-Adam Smith

So my question is, how do I get the filtered results limited to only values that start with the characters entered in the input?

PS: My wording (the title) for this question is quite poor which is probably why I haven't found an answer for this elsewhere. So any tips in rewording the question will probably help a great deal for others looking for a similar solution.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write custom filter:

```
 iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, input) {
    var filtered = [];

   if(input === undefined || input === ''){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

      if(item.name.indexOf(input) == 0){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

and HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchInput" />
<ul class="ng-hide">
  <li ng-repeat="arr in array | myfilter:searchInput">{{ arr.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/glg83UvqmNHCMVMUNJJP?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: The plunker wasn't really working. But you definitely put me in the right direction with custom filters. Thanks for the help mate! Much appreciated!

Comment: You welcome, I checked right now, the Plunker works, I use Chrome, thanks

Comment: Ah, you're right, it does work! I wasn't taking case sensitivity into account, my bad :) Cheers again!